# Good workflow foundation samples

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

Could you please recommend good articles about wofrlow foundation? It would be very good if it will some open source project experience about this technology. My future project will be related to WF and ASP.NET MVC3, so I wish to get some experience before I start the project. Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

It would be very helpful to get more information certainly about WF4 and Flowchart workflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [these](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/tags/WF4/default.aspx) blog post I did or [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd980559#content4) MSDN resources including the videos I did for the MSDN site.

Comment: First link is outdated i guess now its https://blogs.msmvps.com/theproblemsolver/category/wf4-0/

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the PluralSight ones:

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=workflow-by-example&highlight=matt-milner_wf-byexample-workflow-services*0,3,2,4,1,5!matt-milner_wf-byexample-getting-started*0,1!matt-milner_wf-byexample-wf4*0#matt-milner_wf-byexample-workflow-services

You can subscribe for 1 month for free with complete access to presentations, videos and samples.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably start with [the tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735927%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). But there are the [official Microsoft samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741723%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
There is also an even better [collection of links from Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/08/31/Windows-Workflow-Foundation.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your complete and quick answer! That tutoeials is about WF3.5. Could you advice me some samples for newest version WF4? Mostly all my thoughts is about state machines workflows, so it would be very efficient to learn about new Flowchart workflow.

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx) is an introduction to all that's new in WF4. [Here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/flowchartSample/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5105) is a specific sample for the Flowchart workflow. Also, the other answer with Plurasight links will definitely help. G'luck!